# Use Dataframe of Coefficients to Make Test Set Predictions in R

Tags: r, predict

I currently have a data frame similar to:

```
coef_data
  x    y
1  -2 -0.1
2  -2 -0.1
3  -2 -0.1
4  -2 -0.1
5  -2 -0.1
6  -2 -0.1
7  -2 -0.1
8  -2 -0.1
9  -2 -0.1
10 -2 -0.1
11 -2 -0.1
12 -2 -0.1
13 -2 -0.1
14 -2 -0.1
15 -2 -0.1
16 -2 -0.1
17 -2 -0.1
18 -2 -0.1
19 -2 -0.1
20 -2 -0.1
```

where `x` and `y` correspond to the two variables in my linear model. I would like to use each row as a prediction for a given test set (which I have contained in a list). For the sake of the example, I would like to use the first row to make predictions on the below data frame:

```
test_data <- data.frame(replicate(10, rnorm(20)))
colnames(test_data) <- c("ydot", "x", "y", "xx", "xy", "yy", "xxx", "xxy", "xyy", "yyy")
```

I understand that you would typically develop a linear model and use `predict`, but I obtained the coefficients elsewhere. Is there an alternative to the method:

```
predict(coef_data[1, ], test_data)
```

Since using the predict function will give me:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

EDIT:
I have been able to do it manually such that:

```
ydot_prediction <- sqrt(sum(test_data[, 1, drop = FALSE] -
  (coef_data[, 1] * test_data[, 2, drop = FALSE] +
     coef_data[, 2] * test_data[, 3, drop = FALSE])) ^ 2)
```

However, I was hoping to be able to do this automatically. So extracting the columns that have the same name from the `test_data` data frame as the column name in the `coef_data` data frame.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the class of the model? For the standard models, column names should match names present in the model.

Comment: You generate a 20x10 data frame.  How do you wish to combine this with a 6x2 set of coefficients?

Comment: @Henry, sorry, the 6x2 set of coefficients is just from using `head`, so it should be 20x2. The model is a standard linear model. So it should be `y_hat <- -2 * x - 0.1 * y`

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I've added column names to correspond to the dataframe. However, I'd like to create a model such as `y_hat <- -2 * x - 0.1 * y` for prediction in the event that an intercept term is included.

Comment: If the `-0.1` is a constant then you should not be multiplying it by `y`

Comment: @Henry, the `-0.1` is not constant, it corresponds to `y`. Sorry, let me update the example data frame. I am aiming to predict `ydot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this

```
set.seed(2021)
test_data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(7), y=rnorm(7))
test_data$xx <- test_data$x * test_data$x 
test_data$xy <- test_data$x * test_data$y
print(test_data) 
#            x           y         xx           xy
# 1 -0.1224600  0.91556637 0.01499645 -0.112120244
# 2  0.5524566  0.01377194 0.30520833  0.007608399
# 3  0.3486495  1.72996316 0.12155648  0.603150795
# 4  0.3596322 -1.08220485 0.12933535 -0.389195760
# 5  0.8980537 -0.27282518 0.80650043 -0.245011659
# 6 -1.9225695  0.18199540 3.69627356 -0.349898808
# 7  0.2617444  1.50854179 0.06851011  0.394852311

coeff <- c(x=-2, y=-1, xx=+3, xy=+2, constant=+7)
predictions <- as.matrix(cbind(test_data,1)) %*% coeff
print(predictions)
#           [,1]
# [1,]  6.150102
# [2,]  6.812157
# [3,]  6.143709
# [4,]  6.972555
# [5,]  7.406196
# [6,] 21.052167
# [7,]  5.963204
```

where `-2*-0.1224600 -1*0.91556637 +3*0.01499645 +2*-0.112120244 +7` is `6.150102`

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what I need. Is there a way to do it with my current `coef_data` data frame? I get the error `Error in as.matrix(cbind(1, test_data)) %*% as.matrix(coef_data[1,  : 
  non-conformable arguments` presumably because the matrices don't align in shape.

Comment: I was able to sort it out. This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: For the matrix multiplication, you may want to transpose one of the matrices with `t()`